# How to search multiple queries in zend lucene?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have 3 fields two of them are arrays and one is name field. how to search these records from the zend lucene index.

```
code:

$name = $_POST ['name'];

$emails = $_POST ['email']; // this is a array

$xId = $_POST ['xId']; // this also an array

$index = new Zend_Search_Lucene ( 'test-index' );
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little more of what you attempted so far. The code sample does not give much direction. You can build fairly complex queries to search the index, which are essentially boolean queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$name = $_POST ['name'];

$emails = $_POST ['email']; // this is a array

$xIds = $_POST ['xId']; // this also an array

// Making array as string
$emailIds = '';
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $emailIds .= $email . " ";
}

// Making array as string
$xIdsString = '';
foreach ($xIds as $xId) {
    $xIdsString .= $xId . " ";
}

// Create a new index object
$index = new Zend_Search_Lucene ( 'test-index' );

// Here we are going to search over multiple fields. 
// we are just creating the string for right now
$name_query     = "name:($lastName)";
$emails_query   = "emails:($emailIds)";
$xIds_query     = "xIds:($xIdsString)";

// Parse the query
$query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse("$name_query $emails_query $xIds_query");

$hits  = $index->find($query);
print_r($hits);
```